# Timestamp выборка данных за определенное время

Tags: php, mysql

создана таблица с полем time типом  timestamp .ДаннЫе хранятся в формате 
**2013-06-27 14:33:43** 
Как выбрать данные за последний час?
WHERE NOW()-`time`<60*60 не той выдает результат....

```
SELECT `time`,NOW()-`time` AS `diff` ,NOW() AS `NOW`  FROM `users` WHERE status=1

Array ( [time] => 2013-06-27 13:49:51  [diff] => 19100 [NOW] => 2013-06-27 15:40:51 )
```

Как вставить произвольное время в данный тип?
$onlinetime=time();
Если даже вставить такое так пишут нули.

Comment: Ответ :TIMESTAMP()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  `time`,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,`time`, NOW()) AS `diff`,
  CURRENT_TIME() AS `now`
FROM 
  `users` 
WHERE 
  `status` = '1' AND
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,`time`, NOW()) = 0
```

**Добавлено:**

Возможно пригодится [Документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF действительно полезная функция.Благодарен